# marker not showing in google map from json data

Tags: android

I'm a beginner in android please help me, below my code.
I use json file to read markers and insert in google map but marker not showing .I spent a lot of time finding the right solution but unfortunately the problem persists.

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap map;
    //private static final String LOG_TAG = "ExampleApp";

    // private static final String SERVICE_URL = "http://www.web-graphique.fr/lab/geolocalisation/marker_json";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        setUpMapIfNeeded();
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);    
    }

    private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
        if (map == null) {
            SupportMapFragment mapFrag = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map));
            mapFrag.getMapAsync(this);
            if (map != null) {
                //setUpMap();
                new MarkerTask().execute();
            }    
        }
    }    

    private void buildGoogleApiClient() {
    }   

    private class MarkerTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {    

        private static final String TAG = "MyMap";    
        private static final String SERVICE_URL = "http://www.web-graphique.fr/lab/geolocalisation/marker_json";
        // private static final String  SERVICE_URL = " http://localhost/quotes.db/marker_json";

        // Invoked by execute() method of this object
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... args) {

            HttpURLConnection conn = null;
            final StringBuilder json = new StringBuilder();
            try {
                // Connect to the web service
                URL url = new URL(SERVICE_URL);
                conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream());

                // Read the JSON data into the StringBuilder
                int read;
                char[] buff = new char[1024];
                while ((read = in.read(buff)) != -1) {
                    json.append(buff, 0, read);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error connecting to service", e);
                //throw new IOException("Error connecting to service", e); //uncaught
            } finally {
                if (conn != null) {
                    conn.disconnect();
                }
            }

            return json.toString();
        }

        // Executed after the complete execution of doInBackground() method
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String json) {

            try {
                // De-serialize the JSON string into an array of city objects
                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(json);
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject jsonObj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(jsonObj.getJSONArray("latitude").getDouble(0),
                            jsonObj.getJSONArray("latitude").getDouble(0));
                    //move CameraPosition on first result
                    if (i == 0) {
                       CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                                .target(latLng).zoom(13).build();

                        map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
                                .newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));

                    }
                    // Create a marker for each city in the JSON data.
                    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_CYAN))
                            .title(jsonObj.getString("name"))
                            .snippet(Integer.toString(jsonObj.getInt("distance(km)")))
                            .position(latLng));
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error processing JSON", e);
            }
        }    
    }
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        map = googleMap;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                    android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                    == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                buildGoogleApiClient();
                map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

            }
        } else {
            buildGoogleApiClient();
            map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        }
       /*LatLng position = new LatLng(34.734544, 10.755566);
        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(position)
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_CYAN))
                .title("Mosqué"));*/

    }    
}
```

Comment: Are you getting any exception, can you show your logct messages.

Comment: As @amitsingh said, can you show your logcat messages? Can you also post your json? Also, I suspect that not all of this code is relevant to the problem, can you edit to show only the relevant parts? The usual preference is that code be minimal (i.e. no more than is necessary to replicate the error and understand the problem), complete (i.e. enough to understand the context and replicate the problem), and verifiable (i.e. the code you've provided actually has the described problem). See the following: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a issue in here..

change this

```
LatLng latLng = new LatLng(jsonObj.getJSONArray("latitude").getDouble(0),
                    jsonObj.getJSONArray("latitude").getDouble(0));
```

to

```
LatLng latLng = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(jsonObj.getString("latitude")),
                    Double.parseDouble(jsonObj.getString("longitude"));
```

One more issue

change this

```
map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_CYAN))
                    .title(jsonObj.getString("name"))
                    .snippet(Integer.toString(jsonObj.getInt("distance(km)")))
                    .position(latLng));
```

to

```
map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_CYAN))
                    .title(jsonObj.getString("name"))
                    .snippet(jsonObj.getString("distance(km)"))
                    .position(latLng));
```

Hope this works for you!

Comment: thank u very much for your answer but no differences :/

Answer (score 0):

If you get the latitude and longitude you can use this code for showing your marker.

```
//Here lat = lattitude and lon= longitude;

loc = new LatLng(lat, lon);
marker = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(loc).title("NAME").snippet("Now you are here!!"));
```